# I want to track if a user has visits a page in my book content. Is there a a module?

Tags: nodes

I want to be able to keep track of pages in a book and strike out the link in the list of pages if the user has already visited the page. Is this possible?

What's the best module to do this?

Comment: drupal core statistics may help you

Comment: As @harsh mentions, Core has a statistics module. Coupled with views and a bit of field rewriting you should be able to get a class onto rows of book titles already visited.